# istio grpc load balancing outside mesh

Tags: grpc, istio, amazon-elb

Just for the sake of the context, I have this setup:

```
        istio mesh                    external service
          grpc            |        grpc                     2 * istances
app:client -> envoy ->    |     aws classic load balance -> app:server
```

I got two sample applications (client & server ), the client send requests over grpc persistent connection to the server and the server returns its private ip.

I made it work, but the client is always sending requests to the same application instead of round robin between its two instances.

The round robin works if the scenario happens inside the mesh, but not ouside. I'v tried to look at docs to find something, but the examples are all about a mysql server.

I made a test without istio only with the application pointing its connection to envoy (with the envoy configured to proxy the connections to the aws elb) and the round robin happened. I dont know why this doesn't happen when istio is controlling the traffic.

The question is, does anyone knows how to round robin grpc requests (same connection) for external services in istio?

Thanks

Comment: It is totally quiet all around grpc in istio :-I How did you expose grpc via VirtualService and Gateway and opening a port? I have this in github istio: https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7909

Answer (score 1):

gRPC works by leveraging http/2 and making multiple requests over a persistent TCP connection. As such simple connection based load balancing doesn't work like it does for HTTP1.1 requests.

I'm note exactly sure what is happening in your situation but it could be that a single TCP connection is being set up from your Istio Egress gateway to the ELB, which is also making a single TCP connection to one of the instances behind the ELB. All requests are then going over that connection. ELBs don't properly support HTTP/2 either as far as I know, so it could be some protocol dropping or another mechanism that is causing the result.

In terms of fixing it you've got a couple of options that I can think of (disclaimer, I've not had to do this so am theorising):

1. The newer ALB (Application Load Balancer, as opposed to the older ELB) supports HTTP/2 so might operate the way you need if it makes persistent connections to all back end nodes and knows how to load balance those http/2 requests between them
2. Drop the AWS load balancer entirely and instead give the EC2 nodes internet addressable IP addresses (ENIs with a public address), register those addresses in public DNS and then use a gRPC client library which is capable of performing load balancing across those hosts on the client side

Have a read of this for a more in depth explanation: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/11/07/grpc-load-balancing-on-kubernetes-without-tears/

Edit: This thread indicates ALBs don't work 'in a way which gRPC needs', although the information is about a year old: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grpc-io/8s7UHY_Q1po